# Why use Nullable when the type can be assigned Null already?

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm currently working with a library and noticed something weird when using functions I already made(where I must do casting).

The library had a function defined like

```
public DateTime? GetDate(){..}
```

What is the point of this? Why not just make it a regular `DateTime` and return `null` as normal if there is some error getting the date? Am I missing something significant about Nullable types?

Comment: Isn't DateTime a .NET structure? meaning it's a value-type?

Comment: omg. Yea, your right. I'm dumb.. someone can either close this or give me an answer telling me I'm dumb.

Comment: Yea, for some reason I had not yet discovered that DateTime is a value type.. I never had a reason to assign Null to a DateTime I guess..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because DateTime is a .NET value type.  Just like int and char it cannot be null

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is a value type. It cannot have a value of null assigned to it.

Edit: If you attempt to use the ? operator on a reference type, you get the following error:

> The type 'object' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

Answer (score 0):

Value types cannot be Null.  A Nullable (often writen `DateTime?`) can have a value of null.  This is also true for all value types.  If you want a variable to hold a valid Integer or Null, you need to declare a value type of `Int32?`

You cannot have a Nullable string.  I mention this because although strings are reference types they behave like value types in many ways; I have been people try to declare Nullable.  (Okay, I admit it.  It was me.)

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) is a structure and thus a valid nullable because it's a value type. But you're right, one can't make reference types nullable because they can be assigned null already.

Answer (score 0):

Not all types are reference types. For instance you cannot do something like

```
int x = null;
```

because `int` is value type. `DateTime` is value type.

Answer (score 0):

"Why not just make it a regular DateTime and return null"

DateTime can't be null.